# split function in javascript to input type = "text"

Tags: javascript

I've found some code via google that I could use it should be corrected to fit my but when I select something from my drop down menu, nothing happens. have no idea of what I'm doing wrong.

```
<select name="h1" id="h1">
            <?php


            echo "<option value=".$rowlift['H1'].">".$rowlift['H1']."</option>";
                $pris = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM priser ORDER BY id ASC");

            while($rowP = mysql_fetch_assoc($pris))

                echo "<option value='".$rowP['pris'].",".$rowP['id']."'>".$rowP['hojde']. "</option>";
            ?>
        </select>

<?php
            if($rowlift['p1'] != '')
                echo "<input type='text' id='pris1' name='p1' value='".$rowlift['p1']."'>";
            else
                echo "<input type='text' id='pris1' name='p1'>"
            ?>


     <script type="text/javascript">
    var mytextbox = document.getElementById('pris1');
    var mydropdown = document.getElementById('h1');

    var mySplitResult = mydropdown.split(",");

    mydropdown.onchange = function(){
           mytextbox.value = mySplitResult[0];
    }
    </script>
```

i hope this the think you was looking for.. when i select something nothing happens.

```
    <select name="h1" id="h1">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="80,1">1000m</option>
      <option value="90,2">1200m</option>
      <option value="100,3">1500m</option>
      <option value="110,4">2000m</option>
      <option value="120,5">2250m</option>
      <option value="130,6">2500m</option>
      <option value="140,7">3000m</option>
      <option value="150,8">3500m</option>
      <option value="160,9">4000m</option>
      <option value="160,10">Elev man.</option>
      <option value="160,11">Elev auto</option>
      <option value="0,12">HM</option>
      <option value="2000,13">Tandem pass u/video</option>
      <option value="2300,14">Tandem håndhold video</option>
      <option value="2600,15">Tandem pass m/video</option>
      <option value="0,16">Tandem master</option>
      <option value="-100,17">Tandem video</option>
    </select>
   <td>
            <input type="text" id="pris1" name="p1">        <script type="text/javascript">
            var dropdownId = document.getElementById("h1");
            var mytextbox = document.getElementById('pris1');

            var mySplitResult = strUser .split(",");

        dropdownId.onchange = function(){
               mytextbox.value = mySplitResult[1] //to (not) appened
             //mytextbox.innerHTML = this.value;
        }
        </script>

            </td>
```

Comment: Could you add a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Learn to use the browser's console, I am willing to bet there is an error message there that says the problem!

Comment: If it's a JS problem, please post the html markup [output] which the browser receives, not your PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `mydropdown.value.split(',');`

Answer (score 0):

```
var dropdownId = document.getElementById("yourdropdownId");
var strUser = dropdownId .options[dropdownId .selectedIndex].value;

var mySplitResult = strUser .split(",");
```

wrap the above code in onchange()

Answer (score 0):

this is how it should be.. :D

```
  <select name="sel1" id="sel1" onchange ="show()" >
          <option value="">Choose .....</option>
          <option value="80~1">1000m</option>
          <option value="90~2">1200m</option>
          <option value="100~3">1500m</option>
          <option value="110~4">2000m</option>
          <option value="120~5">2250m</option>
          <option value="130~6">2500m</option>
          <option value="140~7">3000m</option>
          <option value="150~8">3500m</option>
          <option value="160~9">4000m</option>
          <option value="160~10">Elev man.</option>
          <option value="160~11">Elev auto</option>
          <option value="0~12">HM</option>
          <option value="2000~3">Tandem pass u/video</option>
          <option value="2300~14">Tandem håndhold video</option>
          <option value="2600~15">Tandem pass m/video</option>
          <option value="0~16">Tandem master</option>
          <option value="-100~17">Tandem video</option>
        </select>
       <td>
    <input type="text" id="pris1" name="pris1">      

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function show() {
    var dropdownId = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
    var mytextbox = document.getElementById('pris1');
    var mySplitResult = dropdownId .split("~");
    mytextbox.value = mySplitResult[0];
    }

    </script>
```